# R documentation formatting for references

Tags: r

In documenting a reference in a manual what are the necessary escaping and formatting needed to display the reference correctly when the package is compiled?  For instance the following is an attempt to format an APA6 style reference for R documentation.

```
\references{
Heylighen, F., \\& Dewaele, J.M. (2002). Variation in the contextuality of language: An
    empirical measure. Context in Context, Special issue of Foundations of Science, 7 (3),
    293-340.
}
```

What would I need to do to this so that it comes out looking about like this:

```
Heylighen, F., & Dewaele, J.M. (2002). Variation in the contextuality of language: 
    An empirical measure. Context in Context, Special issue of Foundations of Science, 
    7 (3), 293-340.
```

Maybe this information is located in some R documentation somewhere.  If this is the case please kindly direct me to rad this passage.

Comment: Look at an example: http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/man/lm.Rd.  They don't escape the &

Comment: perfect, can you give that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on an [.Rd file](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/man/lm.Rd) that has a references section, I think you can simply not escape the ampersand.

Comment: I think the most relevant section of R-exts is [Documenting Functions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions)